# Unknown column for Counting Query

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

```
     tabl1                                 tabl2
[id    -    col1]                   [id  -  tid  -   col1 ]
[1     -     x  ]                   [1   -   1   -    512 ]
                                    [2   -   1   -    512 ]
```

I have the following query

```
$Query = "
SELECT COUNT(a.id), COALESCE(SUM(b.col1), 0) AS sumo 
FROM a.tabl1 
LEFT JOIN b.tabl2 ON a.id = b.tid 
WHERE a.col1 = 'x' AND sumo = 1024
GROUP BY a.id
LIMIT 1
";
```

then i count the total with the following

`$total = $stmt->fetchColumn();`

It is supposed to select the count of rows, Where the `SUM` of `b.col1 = 1024`

The moment i add `WHERE sumo = 1024` it tells me `Unknown column 'sumo'` even after aliasing it as `sumo`, If i removed `COUNT(a.id)` it still tells me that this column is unknown. What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUM` is aggregate function you should use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.id), SUM(b.col1) AS sumo 
FROM tabl1 AS a 
  LEFT JOIN tabl2 AS b ON a.id = b.tid
WHERE b.col2 = 5
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING sumo = 1024
```

or using subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(a.id) AS cnt, SUM(b.col1) AS sumo 
  FROM tabl1 AS a 
    LEFT JOIN tabl2 AS b ON a.id = b.tid
  WHERE b.col2 = 5
  GROUP BY a.id
) AS t
WHERE t.sumo = 1024
```

Comment: Can it be used with `WHERE` clause? If yes, Before or After it?

Comment: `WHERE` can filter if you will use subquery

Comment: There is a weird behavoir i get from using `HAVING` if i used `fetchColumn()` to check the number of rows, I get nothing, But if i used `rowCount()` i get 0, Even tho i only have 1 row with the `sumo = 1024`

Comment: Add some tables data please, it should help to find problem

Comment: Added a minimal table

Comment: Query for your data looks good, try simple run query without `HAVING` statements(without postfilter) and watch query result

Comment: Without `HAVING` i get `Unknown column 'sumo'`, Normally without `WHERE sumo = 1024` get the sumo value out of the table.

Comment: I told about removing `HAVING` and `sumo` filter. Just select `sumo` without any filters

Comment: How exactly? As i understood, Then i should go with `WHERE SUM(b.col1) = 1024`  which would lead to the error `Invalid use of group function`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156758/discussion-between-satandmytro-and-axai).

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause is undoing the outer join.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.id), SUM(b.col1) AS sumo 
FROM a.tabl1 a JOIN
     b.tabl2 b
     ON a.id = b.tid 
WHERE b.col2 = 5 
HAVING sumo = 1024;
```

Comment: tried using having in the query with the same form without the `GROUP BY` or `LIMIT` but got `0` row count from `rowCount()` and didn't get anything at all from `fetchColumn()`